# simpleWebRTC video chat Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': error

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, video-capture, simplewebrtc

Ok so I am doing tutorials on webRTC and I've been using the following two tutorials to help me.

[Sitepoint tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/webrtc-video-chat-application-simplewebrtc/) and [Scotch tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-video-chat-service-with-javascript-webrtc-and-okta)

First thing to note, for the first tutorial even with the source code cloned from github here:

> https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/simplewebrtc-messenger.git

when I deploy the app on Now.sh it works but I am unable to join different users.

**TLDR;**

Here is [My Deployed App](https://simplewebrtc-app-lsjwsabgcv.now.sh/). When I try to join a remote connection I get this error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': 'stun.l.google.com' is not one of the supported URL schemes 'stun', 'turn' or 'turns'.

Here is the [source code

```js
// Code goes here

let username, roomname;
// Determine whether or not we have a querystring.
function hasQueryString() {
    console.log(location.href.indexOf("?"))
    return location.href.indexOf("?") !== -1;
}
const formEl = $('.form');
// Enable video on the page.
function enableVideo() {
    document.getElementById("url").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("remotes").style.visibility = "visible";
    loadSimpleWebRTC();
}

if (hasQueryString()) {
    console.log("Query string!");
    enableVideo();
    if (formEl) {
        formEl.hide();
    }
} else if (formEl) {
    formEl.show();
}

// Handle form submission
console.log("Form loaded!")
$("#join-btn").click(function (event) {
    const formEl = $('.form');
    var usernameInput = formEl.find('#inputUsername');
    var roomnameInput = formEl.find('#inputRoomname');

    if (usernameInput.length > 0 && !usernameInput[0].value) {
        alert("Invalid username!")
    } else if (roomnameInput.length > 0 && !roomnameInput[0].value) {
        alert("Please enter a roomname");
    } else if (roomnameInput.length > 0 && roomnameInput[0].value.length < 6) {
        alert("Roomname must be longer than 5 characters!");
    } else {
        username = usernameInput[0].value;
        roomname = roomnameInput[0].value.toLowerCase();
        window.location = getRoomURL();
        enableVideo();
    }
    return false;
})

// Determine the room name and public URL for this chat session.
function getRoom() {
    if (roomname) {
        return roomname;
    } else {
        var query = location.search && location.search.split("?")[1];
        console.log(query);
        if (query) {
            console.log("roomname is:");
            console.log((location.search && decodeURIComponent(query.split("=")[1]).toLowerCase()));
            roomname = location.search && decodeURIComponent(query.split("=")[1]).toLowerCase();
            return roomname;
        }
    }
    roomname = "room" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
    return roomname;
}

function getUser() {
    if (username) {
        return username;
    } else return "User" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
}


// Retrieve the absolute room URL.
function getRoomURL() {
    return location.protocol + "//" + location.host + (location.path || "") + "?room=" + getRoom();
}

// Dynamically load the simplewebrtc script so that we can
// kickstart the video call.
function loadSimpleWebRTC() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://simplewebrtc.com/latest-v3.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    script.onload = function () {
        var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
            localVideoEl: "selfVideo",
            // the id/element dom element that will hold remote videos
            remoteVideosEl: "",
            autoRequestMedia: true,
            debug: false,
            detectSpeakingEvents: true,
            autoAdjustMic: false
        });

        // Set the publicly available room URL.
        document.getElementById("roomUrl").innerText = getRoomURL();

        // Immediately join room when loaded.
        webrtc.on("readyToCall", function () {
            webrtc.joinRoom(getRoom());
        });

        function showVolume(el, volume) {
            if (!el) return;
            if (volume < -45) volume = -45; // -45 to -20 is
            if (volume > -20) volume = -20; // a good range
            el.value = volume;
        }

        // Display the volume meter.
        webrtc.on("localStream", function (stream) {
            var button = document.querySelector("form>button");
            if (button) button.removeAttribute("disabled");
            document.getElementById("localVolume").style.display = "block";
        });

        // If we didn't get access to the camera, raise an error.
        webrtc.on("localMediaError", function (err) {
            alert("This service only works if you allow camera access.Please grant access and refresh the page.");
        });

        // When another person joins the chat room, we'll display their video.
        webrtc.on("videoAdded", function (video, peer) {
            console.log("user added to chat", peer);
            var remotes = document.getElementById("remotes");

            if (remotes) {
                var outerContainer = document.createElement("div");
                outerContainer.className = "col-md-6";

                var container = document.createElement("div");
                container.className = "videoContainer";
                container.id = "container_" + webrtc.getDomId(peer);
                container.appendChild(video);

                // Suppress right-clicks on the video.
                video.oncontextmenu = function () { return false; };

                // Show the volume meter.
                var vol = document.createElement("meter");
                vol.id = "volume_" + peer.id;
                vol.className = "volume";
                vol.min = -45;
                vol.max = -20;
                vol.low = -40;
                vol.high = -25;
                container.appendChild(vol);

                // Show the connection state.
                if (peer && peer.pc) {
                    var connstate = document.createElement("div");
                    connstate.className = "connectionstate";
                    container.appendChild(connstate);

                    peer.pc.on("iceConnectionStateChange", function (event) {
                        switch (peer.pc.iceConnectionState) {
                            case "checking":
                                connstate.innerText = "connecting to peer...";
                                break;
                            case "connected":
                            case "completed": // on caller side
                                vol.style.display = "block";
                                connstate.innerText = "connection established";
                                break;
                            case "disconnected":
                                connstate.innerText = "disconnected";
                                break;
                            case "failed":
                                connstate.innerText = "connection failed";
                                break;
                            case "closed":
                                connstate.innerText = "connection closed";
                                break;
                        }
                    });
                }

                outerContainer.appendChild(container);
                remotes.appendChild(outerContainer);

                // If we're adding a new video we need to modify bootstrap so we
                // only get two videos per row.
                var remoteVideos = document.getElementById("remotes").getElementsByTagName("video").length;

                if (!(remoteVideos % 2)) {
                    var spacer = document.createElement("div");
                    spacer.className = "w-100";
                    remotes.appendChild(spacer);
                }
            }
        });

        // If a user disconnects from chat, we need to remove their video feed.
        webrtc.on("videoRemoved", function (video, peer) {
            console.log("user removed from chat", peer);
            var remotes = document.getElementById("remotes");
            var el = document.getElementById("container_" + webrtc.getDomId(peer));
            if (remotes && el) {
                remotes.removeChild(el.parentElement);
            }
        });

        // If our volume has changed, update the meter.
        webrtc.on("volumeChange", function (volume, treshold) {
            showVolume(document.getElementById("localVolume"), volume);
        });

        // If a remote user's volume has changed, update the meter.
        webrtc.on("remoteVolumeChange", function (peer, volume) {
            showVolume(document.getElementById("volume_" + peer.id), volume);
        });

        // If there is a P2P failure, we need to error out.
        webrtc.on("iceFailed", function (peer) {
            var connstate = document.querySelector("#container_" + webrtc.getDomId(peer) + " .connectionstate");
            console.log("local fail", connstate);
            if (connstate) {
                connstate.innerText = "connection failed";
                fileinput.disabled = "disabled";
            }
        });

        // remote p2p/ice failure
        webrtc.on("connectivityError", function (peer) {
            var connstate = document.querySelector("#container_" + webrtc.getDomId(peer) + " .connectionstate");
            console.log("remote fail", connstate);
            if (connstate) {
                connstate.innerText = "connection failed";
                fileinput.disabled = "disabled";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```css
body {                                                                                                                        
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;                                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                             
  
  footer {                                                                                                                      
    text-align: center;                                                                                                         
    margin-top: 2em;                                                                                                            
  }                                                                                                                             
  
  h2 {                                                                                                                          
    font-style: italic;                                                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                             
  
  header {                                                                                                                      
    text-align: center;                                                                                                         
    margin: 4em;                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                             
  
  header h1, header h2 {         
    display: inline;             
  }                              
  
  header h1 a, header h2 a, header h1 a:hover, header h2 a:hover {                                                              
    color: inherit;              
    text-decoration: none;       
  }                              
  
  header h2 {                    
    font-size: 24px;             
    padding-left: .5em;          
  }                              
  
  #remotes {                     
    visibility: hidden;          
  }                              
  
  #url {                         
    text-align: center;          
    display: none;               
  }                              
  
  #login {                       
    display: none;               
  }                              
  
  #roomIntro {                   
    font-weight: bold;           
  }
  
  .videoContainer {              
    object-fit: cover;           
    margin: 0 auto;              
    padding: 0;                  
  }                              
  
  .videoContainer video {        
    width: 100%;                 
    height: 100%;                
    border-radius: 10px;         
    border: 5px double #f2f2f2;  
  }                              
  
  .volume {                      
    position: absolute;          
    left: 15%;                   
    width: 70%;                  
    bottom: 20px;                
    height: 10px;                
    display: none;               
  }                              
  
  .connectionstate {             
    position: absolute;          
    top: 10px;                   
    width: 100%;                 
    text-align: center;          
    color: #fff                  
  }                              
  
  .col-md-6 {                    
    margin-bottom: 1em;          
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>vchat - a simple video chat app</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-4.2.2.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div id="enter-form-container" class="jumbotron col-md-6 banner">
        <h1 class="display-4">Web Chat</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a simple free webRTC video chat.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>-->
        <div id="enter-form" class="form">
          <p>Enter a username followed by a room name to join a preexisting room or create a new one.</p>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputUsername1">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" name="username" aria-describedby="usernameHelp" placeholder="Enter Username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Room Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputRoomname" name="roomname" placeholder="Room Name">
          </div>
          <button id="join-btn" class="btn btn-primary submit">Enter Room</button>
        </div>
        <div id="url" class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
          <span id="roomIntro">ROOM URL</span>:
          <span id="roomUrl"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="chat"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="remotes" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="videoContainer">
          <video id="selfVideo" oncontextmenu="return false;"></video>
          <meter id="localVolume" class="volume" min="-45" max="-20" high="-25" low="-40"></meter>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
stun:stun.l.google.com:19302
```

There should be `stun` in the Server URL and indicate the Port Number.

Comment: any idea on how to set that manually? from what I understand simpleWebRTC specifies the default STUN server automatically.

Comment: Simply add `stun:` as the prefix of your stun server path.

Answer (score 0):

OK so apparently there has been some issues with simpleWebRTC's [Sandbox signalling server](https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/issues/702) all week and they also advise that you use your own signaling server.

So I found [XirSys xsdk platform](https://github.com/xirdev/xsdk) and followed their [simpleWebRtc](https://github.com/xirdev/xsdk/blob/master/examples/simplewebrtc.html) example and BOOM! It works.